# Bets Practices for Tree Shaking

Tags: webpack, tree-shaking

I am working on migrating a very old code of Typescript (base on namespace structure).
I am using some external modules like pixijs & have created some of my libs which can be imported by adding in package.json

The issue is webpack (latest version) is not tree shaking the library and it includes all libs along with everyting from pixi.js & other external libs.

So i wanted to ask what are the best settings/configs we should use for webpack.config.js & tsconfig.js to get the best treeshake output js file.